Accessing query results from DBT in python script
I am doing a bunch of programmatic running of dbt models from a python script. Part of this is the need to access the results of a simple query to determine what to do next. The dbtRunnerResult object never seems to have the query results, no matter whether I run a model or an operation. So so far I've gotten a workaround to execute a macro that then logs the rows of the query result and I parse that from the stdout of a subprocess in python like so:
The dbt macro:
{% macro execute_sql(query) %}
{% set results = run_query(query) %}
{% for row in results %}
{{ log('counter=='~row[0], info=True) }}
{% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

and here's the python script:
import subprocess
import json
import re

# Define a function to run the dbt command and capture the output
def run_dbt_command(command):
    result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True)
    return result.stdout, result.stderr

# Define the SQL query
sql_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbt.model_x"

# Run the SQL query using the execute_sql macro
command = [
    'dbt',
    'run-operation',
    'execute_sql',
    '--args',
    json.dumps({"query": sql_query})
]

stdout, stderr = run_dbt_command(command)

# Access the query results from the log output
if "counter==" in stdout:
    print("Query executed successfully")
    # Extract the rows from the log output
    rows = re.findall(r'counter==(\d+)', stdout)
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
else:
    print("Query execution failed")
    print(stderr)

This does let me access the log output from the macro but this feels really dumb and I'd much rather do something like
from dbt.cli.main import dbtRunner, dbtRunnerResult
from dbt.contracts.graph.manifest import Manifest

# Initialize the dbt runner and parse the manifest
res: dbtRunnerResult = dbtRunner().invoke(["parse"])
manifest: Manifest = res.result
dbt = dbtRunner(manifest=manifest)

sql_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbt.model_x"

run: dbtRunnerResult = dbt.invoke([
    'run-operation',
    'execute_sql',
    '--args',
    json.dumps({"query": sql_query})
])

if run.success:
    print("Query executed successfully")
    results = run.result.results.something

I'm running dbt version 1.8 and various old pieces around the internet around dbt-rpc or dbt.get_results(query) just aren't a thing anymore.
EDIT:
The reason I want to use DBT for this query running is so that I don't have to have a DBT client and corresponding DB client (e.g. psycopg2, clickhouse-connect / clickhouse-driver) to run queries separately and handle auth & connections and whatnot.

So I found a more "dbt" way for my use case. It doesn't give me query results back per-se, but since I need it only for some branching if/else logic, I made a test for it.
-- test/check_model_x.sql
with tests as (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM {{ ref('model_x') }} WHERE some_condition = 1
)
SELECT 'name_of_test', cnt FROM tests where cnt > 0

Then my python script looks like this:
from dbt.cli.main import dbtRunner, dbtRunnerResult
from dbt.contracts.graph.manifest import Manifest

class MyLooper():

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize the dbt runner and parse the manifest
        res: dbtRunnerResult = dbtRunner().invoke(["parse"])
        manifest: Manifest = res.result
        self.dbt = dbtRunner(manifest=manifest)

        self.loop_counter = 0
        self.is_done = False

    def start_base(self):
        self.dbt.invoke([
            'run',
            '-s',
            'model_x'
            '--full-refresh',
            '--quiet'
        ])
        print('running full refresh')
        


    def check_x(self):
        self.loop_counter += 1
        run : dbtRunnerResult = self.dbt.invoke([
            'test',
            '-s',
            'check_model_x',
            '--quiet'
        ])

        if run.success:
            print(f"test success after run {self.loop_counter}")
            return True
        else:
            print(f"test failed after run {self.loop_counter}")
            return False
        
    def reduce_x(self):
        while (self.is_done is False and self.loop_counter <= 10):
            self.is_done = self.check_x()
            if self.is_done is False:
                print('running reducer') 
                self.dbt.invoke([
                    'run',
                    '-s',
                    'model_x',
                    '--quiet'
                ])
        if (self.is_done is False and self.loop_counter > 10):
            print("error, stopped reducing after max tries")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    runner = MyLooper()
    runner.start_base()
    runner.reduce_x()

DBT tests will fail if they return anything, so by wrapping my count(*) query in a CTE and selecting from it only when that count is > 0, I get a test that fails when I need to run my incremental model again.
The loop_counter variable is just there to prevent an infinite loop possibility.
The DBT STDOUT looks something like this when I run it:
11:10:27  Running with dbt=1.8.8
11:10:27  Registered adapter: clickhouse=1.8.4
11:10:28  Performance info: /path/to/project/target/perf_info.json
11:10:29  1 of 1 FAIL 1 check_x ...................................................... [FAIL 1 in 0.07s]
11:10:29  Failure in test check_edges (tests/check_model_x.sql)
11:10:29    Got 1 result, configured to fail if != 0
test failed after run 1
...................................................... [FAIL 1 in 0.14s]
....
...more  runs...
....
11:10:46  1 of 1 FAIL 1 check_x ...................................................... [FAIL 1 in 0.06s]
11:10:46  Failure in test check_edges (tests/check_model_x.sql)
11:10:46    Got 1 result, configured to fail if != 0
test failed after run 6
running reducer
test success after run 7

Like I said, not actually a way to get query results cleanly back from DBT runs, but serving the purpose of being able to make decicisions based on a query result. This can likely be extended with custom test logic in DBT that would give more than a pass/fail in run.result.results[0].message, but this is good enough for me at the moment.

From https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/programmatic-invocations#dbtrunnerresult:

result: If the command completed (successfully or with handled errors), its result(s). Return type varies by command.

In particular, run_operation:

ignores the result of self._run_unsafe(package_name, macro_name), and
hardcodes message=None.

As of dbt 1.8, extensive monkey-patching is required to achieve usage:
if run.success:
    print("Query executed successfully")
    # results = run.result.results.something
    count = run.result.results[0].agate_table.rows[0]["count"]

Also, your macro is missing a return function call:
{% macro execute_sql(query) %}
{% set results = run_query(query) %}
{{ return(results) }}
{% endmacro %}

Monkey-patching
1. Patch RunOperationTask.run to return agate_table in result
Notable lines marked with # Answer.
def patch_RunOperationTask__run():
    import os
    import threading
    import traceback
    from datetime import datetime

    import agate
    import dbt_common.exceptions
    from dbt.contracts.files import FileHash
    from dbt.contracts.graph.nodes import HookNode
    from dbt.artifacts.schemas.results import RunStatus, TimingInfo
    from dbt.artifacts.schemas.run import RunResultsArtifact, RunResult
    from dbt_common.events.functions import fire_event
    from dbt.events.types import (
        LogDebugStackTrace,
        RunningOperationCaughtError,
        RunningOperationUncaughtError,
    )
    from dbt_common.exceptions import DbtInternalError
    from dbt.node_types import NodeType

    RESULT_FILE_NAME = "run_results.json"

    def run(self) -> RunResultsArtifact:
        start = datetime.utcnow()
        self.compile_manifest()

        success = True
        res = None  # Answer

        package_name, macro_name = self._get_macro_parts()

        try:
            res = self._run_unsafe(package_name, macro_name)  # Answer
        except dbt_common.exceptions.DbtBaseException as exc:
            fire_event(RunningOperationCaughtError(exc=str(exc)))
            fire_event(LogDebugStackTrace(exc_info=traceback.format_exc()))
            success = False
        except Exception as exc:
            fire_event(RunningOperationUncaughtError(exc=str(exc)))
            fire_event(LogDebugStackTrace(exc_info=traceback.format_exc()))
            success = False

        agate_table = res if isinstance(res, agate.Table) else None  # Answer

        end = datetime.utcnow()

        macro = (
            self.manifest.find_macro_by_name(macro_name, self.config.project_name, package_name)
            if self.manifest
            else None
        )

        if macro:
            unique_id = macro.unique_id
            fqn = unique_id.split(".")
        else:
            raise DbtInternalError(
                f"dbt could not find a macro with the name '{macro_name}' in any package"
            )

        run_result = RunResult(
            adapter_response={},
            status=RunStatus.Success if success else RunStatus.Error,
            execution_time=(end - start).total_seconds(),
            failures=0 if success else 1,
            message=None,
            node=HookNode(
                alias=macro_name,
                checksum=FileHash.from_contents(unique_id),
                database=self.config.credentials.database,
                schema=self.config.credentials.schema,
                resource_type=NodeType.Operation,
                fqn=fqn,
                name=macro_name,
                unique_id=unique_id,
                package_name=package_name,
                path="",
                original_file_path="",
            ),
            thread_id=threading.current_thread().name,
            timing=[TimingInfo(name=macro_name, started_at=start, completed_at=end)],
            agate_table=agate_table,  # Answer
        )

        results = RunResultsArtifact.from_execution_results(
            generated_at=end,
            elapsed_time=(end - start).total_seconds(),
            args={
                k: v
                for k, v in self.args.__dict__.items()
                if k.islower() and type(v) in (str, int, float, bool, list, dict)
            },
            results=[run_result],
        )

        result_path = os.path.join(self.config.project_target_path, RESULT_FILE_NAME)

        if self.args.write_json:
            results.write(result_path)

        return results

    from dbt.task.run_operation import RunOperationTask  # Answer
    RunOperationTask.run = run  # Answer

2. Patch process_run_result to return agate_table in output
Notable lines marked with # Answer.
def patch_run__process_run_result():
    from dataclasses import dataclass, field

    import agate
    from dbt.artifacts.schemas.run import RunResult, RunResultOutput
    from dbt.artifacts.resources.v1.components import CompiledResource

    @dataclass
    class MyRunResultOutput(RunResultOutput):
        agate_table: agate.Table = field(metadata={"serialize": "omit"})  # Answer

    def process_run_result(result: RunResult) -> RunResultOutput:
        compiled = isinstance(result.node, CompiledResource)

        return MyRunResultOutput(  # Answer
            unique_id=result.node.unique_id,
            status=result.status,
            timing=result.timing,
            thread_id=result.thread_id,
            execution_time=result.execution_time,
            message=result.message,
            adapter_response=result.adapter_response,
            failures=result.failures,
            compiled=result.node.compiled if compiled else None,  # type:ignore
            compiled_code=result.node.compiled_code if compiled else None,  # type:ignore
            relation_name=result.node.relation_name if compiled else None,  # type:ignore
            agate_table=result.agate_table,  # Answer
        )

    from dbt.artifacts.schemas.run.v5 import run  # Answer
    run.process_run_result = process_run_result  # Answer

Register a custom command
A better way that is less likely to break when dbt version updates come out is to subclass RunOperationTask and register a custom @cli.command("run-operation-with-results").
Usage:
# import run_operation_with_results  # Register run-operation-with-results
run: dbtRunnerResult = dbt.invoke([
    # 'run-operation',             # Change this
    'run-operation-with-results',  # to this
    'execute_sql',
    '--args',
    json.dumps({"query": sql_query})
])

run_operation_with_results.py:
import copy
import os
import threading
import traceback
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Dict, Sequence

import agate
import click
import dbt_common.exceptions
from dbt.artifacts.resources.v1.components import CompiledResource
from dbt.artifacts.schemas.results import RunStatus, TimingInfo
from dbt.artifacts.schemas.run import RunResult, RunResultOutput, RunResultsArtifact, RunResultsMetadata
from dbt.cli import dbt_cli as cli, params as p, requires
from dbt.cli.main import global_flags
from dbt.contracts.files import FileHash
from dbt.contracts.graph.nodes import HookNode
from dbt.events.types import LogDebugStackTrace, RunningOperationCaughtError, RunningOperationUncaughtError
from dbt.exceptions import scrub_secrets
from dbt.node_types import NodeType
from dbt.task.run_operation import RunOperationTask
from dbt_common.constants import SECRET_ENV_PREFIX
from dbt_common.events.functions import fire_event
from dbt_common.exceptions import DbtInternalError


@cli.command("run-operation-with-results")
@click.pass_context
@global_flags
@click.argument("macro")
@p.args
@p.profiles_dir
@p.project_dir
@p.target_path
@p.threads
@p.vars
@requires.postflight
@requires.preflight
@requires.profile
@requires.project
@requires.runtime_config
@requires.manifest
def run_operation_with_results(ctx, **kwargs):
    """Run the named macro with any supplied arguments."""
    task = RunOperationWithResultsTask(
        ctx.obj["flags"],
        ctx.obj["runtime_config"],
        ctx.obj["manifest"],
    )

    results = task.run()
    success = task.interpret_results(results)
    return results, success


RESULT_FILE_NAME = "run_results.json"


class RunOperationWithResultsTask(RunOperationTask):
    def run(self) -> RunResultsArtifact:
        start = datetime.utcnow()
        self.compile_manifest()

        success = True
        res = None

        package_name, macro_name = self._get_macro_parts()

        try:
            res = self._run_unsafe(package_name, macro_name)
        except dbt_common.exceptions.DbtBaseException as exc:
            fire_event(RunningOperationCaughtError(exc=str(exc)))
            fire_event(LogDebugStackTrace(exc_info=traceback.format_exc()))
            success = False
        except Exception as exc:
            fire_event(RunningOperationUncaughtError(exc=str(exc)))
            fire_event(LogDebugStackTrace(exc_info=traceback.format_exc()))
            success = False

        agate_table = res if isinstance(res, agate.Table) else None

        end = datetime.utcnow()

        macro = (
            self.manifest.find_macro_by_name(macro_name, self.config.project_name, package_name)
            if self.manifest
            else None
        )

        if macro:
            unique_id = macro.unique_id
            fqn = unique_id.split(".")
        else:
            raise DbtInternalError(
                f"dbt could not find a macro with the name '{macro_name}' in any package"
            )

        run_result = RunResult(
            adapter_response={},
            status=RunStatus.Success if success else RunStatus.Error,
            execution_time=(end - start).total_seconds(),
            failures=0 if success else 1,
            message=None,
            node=HookNode(
                alias=macro_name,
                checksum=FileHash.from_contents(unique_id),
                database=self.config.credentials.database,
                schema=self.config.credentials.schema,
                resource_type=NodeType.Operation,
                fqn=fqn,
                name=macro_name,
                unique_id=unique_id,
                package_name=package_name,
                path="",
                original_file_path="",
            ),
            thread_id=threading.current_thread().name,
            timing=[TimingInfo(name=macro_name, started_at=start, completed_at=end)],
            agate_table=agate_table,
        )

        results = RunResultsArtifact.from_execution_results(
            generated_at=end,
            elapsed_time=(end - start).total_seconds(),
            args={
                k: v
                for k, v in self.args.__dict__.items()
                if k.islower() and type(v) in (str, int, float, bool, list, dict)
            },
            results=[run_result],
        )

        result_path = os.path.join(self.config.project_target_path, RESULT_FILE_NAME)

        if self.args.write_json:
            results.write(result_path)

        return results


@dataclass
class RunResultsArtifact(RunResultsArtifact):

    @classmethod
    def from_execution_results(
        cls,
        results: Sequence[RunResult],
        elapsed_time: float,
        generated_at: datetime,
        args: Dict,
    ):
        processed_results = [
            cls.process_run_result(result) for result in results if isinstance(result, RunResult)
        ]
        meta = RunResultsMetadata(
            dbt_schema_version=str(cls.dbt_schema_version),
            generated_at=generated_at,
        )

        secret_vars = [
            v for k, v in args["vars"].items() if k.startswith(SECRET_ENV_PREFIX) and v.strip()
        ]

        scrubbed_args = copy.deepcopy(args)

        # scrub secrets in invocation command
        scrubbed_args["invocation_command"] = scrub_secrets(
            scrubbed_args["invocation_command"], secret_vars
        )

        # scrub secrets in vars dict
        scrubbed_args["vars"] = {
            k: scrub_secrets(v, secret_vars) for k, v in scrubbed_args["vars"].items()
        }

        return cls(
            metadata=meta, results=processed_results, elapsed_time=elapsed_time, args=scrubbed_args
        )

    @classmethod
    def process_run_result(cls, result):
        compiled = isinstance(result.node, CompiledResource)

        return RunResultOutput(
            unique_id=result.node.unique_id,
            status=result.status,
            timing=result.timing,
            thread_id=result.thread_id,
            execution_time=result.execution_time,
            message=result.message,
            adapter_response=result.adapter_response,
            failures=result.failures,
            compiled=result.node.compiled if compiled else None,  # type:ignore
            compiled_code=result.node.compiled_code if compiled else None,  # type:ignore
            relation_name=result.node.relation_name if compiled else None,  # type:ignore
            agate_table=result.agate_table,
        )


@dataclass
class RunResultOutput(RunResultOutput):
    agate_table: agate.Table = field(metadata={"serialize": "omit"})


That makes sense but I want to stay away from having to do this kind of monkey patching. So far the method of running specific tests that pass or fail is workable and less likely to break when DBT version updates come out. Thank you very much for confirming that I'm not crazy when I couldn't get it to give me results with "normal" usage!

Thank you for the feedback. I added a solution to register a custom command in a way that is less likely to break when dbt version updates come out.

I created a PR at dbt-labs/dbt-core#10957 to add this feature into dbt itself.
